# How to fix "running openshift on a specific Interface"

Tags: openshift-origin

I have a server with 4 interface, installing openshift on the server causes errors,how can I set openshift to listen on one interface ??

Answer (score 0):

fixed by

```
[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=okd
ansible_become=true
openshift_deployment_type=origin

openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]

openshift_master_default_subdomain=apps.sgas.ir

openshift_docker_insecure_registries=172.30.0.0/16

openshift_disable_check=disk_availability,docker_image_availability

[masters]
master.sgas.ir openshift_schedulable=true containerized=false

[etcd]
master.sgas.ir  openshift_ip=172.16.110.42

[nodes]
master.sgas.ir openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master-infra' openshift_ip=172.16.110.42
node1.sgas.ir openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute' openshift_ip=172.16.110.43
```

but still have error on installing monitoring part